# How to prove something about the order of element at a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

$G$ is a **cyclic** group. the order of $G$ is $n$ ($|G|=n$).
$m\mid n$,
I have to prove that there is $b\in G$ that $ord(b)=m$.

Know, here is one part of the proof:

if $m\mid n$ that means that $n=mk$. Lets mark:
$$b=a^k$$ 
then: $$b^m=(a^k)^m=a^n=e\Rightarrow ord(b)=m$$

Now I need to prove that $m$ is minimal.
How I'm prove this?

Thank you!

Comment: In general,this is true if $G$ is abelian or $p$-group or nilpotent. Is one of these true?

Comment: A variety of results similar to what was asked can be found in http://math.stackexchange.com/a/41762/73324

Comment: The claim, as written, is false: $\;|A_4|=12\;\;\text{and}\;\;6\mid 12\;$ , yet $\;A_4\;$ has no element of order $\;6\;$ ...

Comment: This is true if m is prime, but is not in general true if m is composite, even if G is abelian.

Comment: @Syd It is true for finite abelian groups.

Comment: I forgoet to add one important thing....
I add it! The group is cyclic... Sorry....

Comment: We can't use Lagrange's Theorem, because we didn't learn it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer to Original Post, Before Edit:**

The theorem you are trying to prove, as stated, is not true. The converse of Lagrange's Theorem does not, in general, hold.

For example, take $A_4$, the alternating group of $S_4$. $\;|A_4| = 12$, and clearly, $\;6\mid 12.\;$ However, there is no subgroup of order $6$ in $A_4$, and hence, no element $b\in A_4$ whose order is $6$.

So Lagrange holds here, and the corresponding Corollary that for every element $b\in A_4$, the order of $b$ divides the order of $A_4$ is of course true, but it does not follow that if $m$ divides the order of a group, then there is an element of order $m$.

With limitations, the theorem is true. Specifically,

- if $G$ is a finite abelian group, or
- if the order of $G$ is a power of a prime, or
- if $G$ is solvable,

then the statement is true.

---

After edit: Indeed, this is true for the finite cyclic group $G$.

Suggestion about the initial part of your proof: Make sure you make explicit that, since G is cyclic, it is generated by one element, we'll call $a$. So $\langle a\rangle = G$. Then it follows that there is some element $b \in G$ such that $b = a^k$, where $0\leq k \lt n$.

To show that $m$ is minimal, we can show that if there exists $0\leq s \lt m$ such that $b^s = e$, then $s = 0$. Or else you can assume, for the sake of contradiction, that there exists an $s$, $0\lt s \lt m$ such that $b^s = e$, and obtain a contradiction.

Comment: I forget to mention - G is a cyclic group. Now How can I prove it?

Comment: This isn't true. For example, The additive group of the field of order 8 has no element of order 4.

(I'm responding to amWhy, not Yoav.)

Comment: How do you prove the last part?
(what you added).
Can you write it to me? 
Thank you so much!!

Comment: @amWhy - please answer me...

Comment: Bon Appetit! I'm waiting for the proof...
Thank you so much! And I'm sorry if I'm disturbing you. You help me a lot!!
:-)

Comment: I'm still waiting for the answer...:-)

Comment: @Yoav Are you still stuck on this question? If so, I will elaborate a bit this afternoon, I promise!

Comment: No, it's OK, I solve it! But thank you! If I had more questions I'll ask :-)