# Understanding Converse of Lagrange's theorem!

Tags: logic, finite-groups

Lagrange's theorem states that for any finite group $G$, the order (number of elements) of every subgroup $H$ of $G$ divides the order of $G$ .......(1)

The converse of Lagrange's theorem is if $x$ divides order of $G$ ,then **there exists** a sub group of order $x$.                 ......         (2)

If my statement is $p\to q$ then converse is $q\to p$.

i couldn't understand how converse of Lagrange's theorem comes...please explain with this definition of converse : $p\to q$ then converse is $q\to p$

Comment: (I'm sorry if this question is uninteresting But please help!)

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/41762/8581

Comment: I don't want counter example! i want to know how (2) is converse of (1)

Comment: I have given an answer for how to formulate the converse of the Lagrange's theorem. However, the other answers as for the counterexample to disprove the converse statement are also correct!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, you need to write the Lagrange theorem in $p \rightarrow q$ form. So, the Lagrange theorem is actually,

If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then order of $H$ divides order of $G$.

Here $p:$ $H$ is a subgroup of $G$

$q;$ Order of $H$ divides order of $G$.

Here, actually the existence of $H$ is in the hypothesis ($p$) and the number $m$ is actually the order of the subgroup which divides order of $G$.

So, the converse will be

If a number $m$ divides order of $G$, then there is a subgroup of order $m$.

I hope this gives you insights.

Comment: It seems that the OP gets trouble in understanding a logical statement.

Comment: @ResidentDementor yes you are correct

Comment: Yes. Actually he does! Which is why I think that he should have made the tag of "logic" instead of "abstract algebra".

Comment: well i change the tags.. thanks for your suggestion

Comment: So Lagrange's theorem can be restated  as If there exists a subgroup H of order m ,then m | order of G.. Is this correct?

Comment: Absolutely correct!

Comment: I'd write the converse of Lagrange's theorem like this: "For every finite group $G$, if $d$ divides $|G|$ then there exists a subgroup $H$ of $G$ with $|H|=d$ ". And so, to disprove this statement you just have to prove its negation which is, "There exists a finite group $G$ such that $d$ divides $|G|$ and there do not exist any subgroup $H$ of $G$ with  $|H|=d$ ". To add further, one such finite group $G$ is $A_4$.

Answer (score -2):

Take the group $A_4$, then group of all even permutations of $4$ elements. $o(A_4)$ is $12$, but it doesn't have any subgroup of order $6$. Please check it !!

Comment: I don't want counter example! i want to know how (2) is converse of (1)

Comment: The order of $A_4$ is $12$

Comment: Yes, you're right @leibnewtz. My mistake !!